# Tensorflow FIFOQueue enqueue sparse array

Tags: arrays, deep-learning, tensorflow

How can I feed a FIFOQueue with sparse array?

I have variable size of bbox for each image so I am using two queues in order to receive an image and the corresponding object bboxes.

```
data = [[[1619, 1153, 1977, 1733]], [[1488, 3569, 1594, 3604], [1282, 3476, 1382, 3526], [1667, 3613, 1814, 3653], [2374, 3459, 2848, 3632]],[[2207, 3513, 2671, 3632]], [[2554, 1222, 2865, 1377]]]
data_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=5, dtypes=[tf.int32, tf.int32], shapes=[[None], [5]])

data_enqueue_op = data_queue.enqueue_many([data])
```

This code gives `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: What is `data`?  When reporting an error, the polite thing to do is include at least some of the stack trace.

Comment: I did not mean to be rude. Data is "input", I updated the question. I am not asking about particular error but a concept. These are couple of lines that I copied from my project to make it more understandable. Therefore, actual stack trace is not that much helpful in this case. ValueError occurs at enqueue_many. Thank you for catching the wrong variable name.

Comment: As of june 2017 enqueueing sparse tensors is not supported. The best way around it is to serialize the sparse tensor into a string somehow, enqueue that, and deserialize on the other end.